# Undefined value when passing data from android to javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm using this code but the value said "undefined" can anyone point me the problem?

this is my java class codes

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.frux.web.R.layout.activity_main);
    String value = "Isiah";
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/webpage");
    web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue("+ value +")");


}
```

and this is my webpage codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

Whats your Name?
<input id="name" value="" />
<button onclick = "setValue()">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setValue(value){
var myValue = value;
document.getElementById("name").value = myValue;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any thoughts will be highly appreciated

Comment: I post an answer assuming that by HTML variable you meant javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript side:

```
function setValue(value){
   myValue=value;
}
```

In Java side:

> myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setValue("+value+");");

Comment: by using this code function setValue(value){
   myValue=value;
} I can now use the myValue in my html?

Comment: You have to use DOM API of Javascript to "modify" you HTML. You can also compose a html in a string and pass it to a `WebView` using `myWebView.loadData(myHtmlString,"text/html",null)`

Comment: `myHtmlString = "<HTML><BODY><TEXTAREA>" + myValue + "</TEXTAREA></BODY></HTML>"` ???

Comment: but i need to set the textbox in my web page using javascript and i using this code but its not working                                             <SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"JavaScript\">" 
 function setValue(value){
   var myValue=value;
   myValue = document.getElementsByName("name").value;
   
 }
</script>

Comment: Shouldn't be otherwise? `document.getElementsByName("name").value = myValue;`. Because the way you wrote, you are copying what is in the field to myValue